# If else formula does not evaluate?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I am writing a simple formula in crystal reports. What I am trying to do is to calculate a total based on some conditions, store the result in a shared numberVar, then return the result. However, I get an error right after my else

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
EvaluateAfter({@Share_Hundred_Percent});
EvaluateAfter({@Less_Commission});
EvaluateAfter({@Payment_NICL});
EvaluateAfter({@Payment_PRCL});

Shared numberVar sumNetPayable;
numberVar result;

if({Command.GENCLIENTCODE}=990) then
    result:= {@Share_Hundred_Percent} - {@Less_Commission} + {@Payment_PRCL};
else
    result:= {@Share_Hundred_Percent} - {@Less_Commission};

sumNetPayable := sumNetPayable + result;

result
```

> The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Remove semicolon for `Then` in `If`

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
EvaluateAfter({@Share_Hundred_Percent});
EvaluateAfter({@Less_Commission});
EvaluateAfter({@Payment_NICL});
EvaluateAfter({@Payment_PRCL});

Shared numberVar sumNetPayable;
numberVar result;

if({Command.GENCLIENTCODE}=990) then
    result:= {@Share_Hundred_Percent} - {@Less_Commission} + {@Payment_PRCL}
else
    result:= {@Share_Hundred_Percent} - {@Less_Commission};

sumNetPayable := sumNetPayable + result;

result
```

Comment: thanks, I removed both semicolons by mistake. It works now although the result is wrong.

Comment: You are welcome.. I think you need to check the calculation for result part.

Comment: thanks for your input. I created a new question cannot understand the cause